# Coldfusion alternative to evaluate() to return a value from a query dynamically

Tags: coldfusion

I am stuck trying to work out the correct notation to use instad of the `evaluate()` function. Let me try and explain:

I have a several components: `tasks.cfc`, `risks.cfc` ...etc each with their respective functions. The naming convention is similar for example in the tasks.cfc

I have the method `countAllFunctionInstanceTasks`, the return variable is the same name (`countAllFunctionInstanceTasks`) and in the `risks.cfc` I have the equivalent method `countAllFunctionInstanceRisks` and its retun variable is the same name (`countAllFunctionInstanceRisks`). Each return variable is a structure with the following keys:

```
totalRed
totalAmber
totalGreen
totalComplete
totalOpen
```

When I invoke the component I do this dynamically:

```
<cfinvoke component="components.#session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]#" 
    method="countAllFunctionInstance#session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]#" 
    returnvariable="countAllFunctionInstance#session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]#">
```

All the `[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]` is doing is pulling a value from a set of nested structures and will retun the value (keeping it to the example above) "tasks" or "risks".

This bit is working fine and it retuns the respecive values as expected so for example if I where to:

```
<cfoutput>#countAllFunctionInstanceTasks.totalOpen#</cfoutput>
```

I will get the correct value from the tasks.cfc and

```
<cfoutput>#countAllFunctionInstanceRisks.totalOpen#</cfoutput>
```

I will get the correct value from the `risks.cfc`.

So far so good but...I need to get these values dynamically but I am struggling to get the correct notation to dynamically return the respective values. So I coud do something like:

```
<p>countAllFunctionInstance#session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]#.totalOpen</p>
```

which will return the string:

```
"countAllFunctionInstanceTasks.totalOpen"
"countAllFunctionInstanceRisks.totalOpen"
```

But what I am tring to do is dynamically generate the variable name that alread exists and has been retuned from the respective cfc's.

So far all I have been able to get working is this:

```
<cfset totalOpen = "countAllFunctionInstance#session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]#.totalOpen" />
<cfoutput>#evaluate(totalOpen)#</cfoutput>
```

I understand using the `evaluate()` function is not good practice and I trying to find an alternative notation something like:

```
#["countAllFunctionInstance" & session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"] & ".totalOpen"]#
```

I have read the other posts I can find on evaluate() alternatives and array notation but these are not quite the same as my use case here and after several attempts and connotations, nothing has worked and I am totally stumped!

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you,

James

Answer (score 5):

The string that you're calling with `evaluate()`:

```
#["countAllFunctionInstance" & session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"] & ".totalOpen"]#
```

The variable `countAllFunctionInstance` should be in the `variables` scope of the request. So you should be able to reference it something like this:

```
variables["countAllFunctionInstance" & session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]].totalOpen
```

or

```
variables["countAllFunctionInstance" & session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]]["totalOpen"]
```

or

```
x = variables["countAllFunctionInstance" & session.myPermissions[i][j][k][l][m][n][o]["activityName"]];
#x.totalOpen#
```